# Where did Moses' applied scientific knowledge disappear?

Tags: halacha-theory, moshe-rabbeinu, science

I had a series of seemingly true statements that lead me to a contradiction I'm unable to solve:

1. Moses knew all the Torah => Moses knew all the Halacha.
2. Moses knew all the Halochos of Shabbos => when Shabbos starts and ends => Shabbos doesn't start simultaneously everywhere, there are places with no Tzeis or Neitz at all and at the poles there's no time to tell.

Then Moses *had to know* that the Earth is round and the Sun revolves around it and differences between time zones and latitudes. And he had to pass all that knowledge on to Neviim up to Knesset Hagdolah.

However, nowhere in our sources, this Halachicly necessary knowledge is mentioned and it is completely "lost" for millennia.

How the total lack of this knowledge through the following generations can be explained?

---

A lot of people are trying to prove that sages knew numerous scientific facts by interpreting their vague statements, but my point is that that knowledge should always have been a part of the Jewish Halachah starting with Moses, the fact we don't find in our sources.

Comment: Why did Moshe have to know about time zones? He would know how to look outside and see stars. That's all anyone needs to know to determine the end of Shabbat.

Comment: Without questioning the validity of your 'seemingly true statements', how would you have expected this to be recorded? Let's say Moshe did know everything about chemistry, he still only wrote 5 books. Were you expecting a sixth book about chemistry (and a seventh about metallurgy, and an eight about... etc.)?

Comment: @Salmononius2 I would love if you can repudiate the statements. I'm looking for a way to reconcile the well-known facts, that's all. I have no problem accepting that Moses knew all those facts, then where did it go away?

Comment: @DoubleAA Please do try to refuse the reasoning I presented. You (and your followers) contradict the first statement - you're saying, Moses didn't get the complete Halacha, only what N"M for their generation. Then it's not the whole Torah, Isn't it?

Comment: I can't respond to claims containing ambiguous terminology.

Comment: @AlBerko I'm not here to argue with your statements of fact. I'm saying that even if they were true, why would it be surprising that they weren't all explicitly and fully transmitted in our sources? By the time Yehoshua was around, we had already lost 300 Halachos from Moshe. Throughut history, we had to write up the Mishna, Gemara, Meforshim, etc in order to retain as much as we can. So why would it be unreasonable to suggest that Moshe knew all the sciences, but throughout the ages it was forgotten (like much of the Oral Torah)?

Comment: @Salmononius2 This is a possible answer - post it, I'd upvote it - you claim it was immediately forgotten. A very plausible explanation. I only ask where did it go, and you answer.

Comment: Rav Asher Weiss says the obvious fact: Hashem could have given Moshe a science book, but he didn't. He have him the Torah. You don't need to know the scientific facts if you have all the halachos. He knew what to do if there's no sunset or sunrise. Just like the gemarras that discuss outlandish cases are presenting a true halacha, even if they at the time had no conception of airplanes or electricity or whatever, it didn't matter.

Comment: @robev It appears the opposite - the science book that G-d gave to Moses IS the Torah - that's the book that is presumed to include everything. Or Hashem could give Moses the Oral law book but He didn't. This argument is totally lame. 2. I claim Moses couldn't do Halacha without knowing science just like we couldn't do it. Please stop and think before you throw cheap Teshuvah arguments. 3. I didn't claim Moses didn't know it, I asked where did it disappear?

Comment: I know what you asked. As usual I'm informing you that your premises may be false

Comment: @AlBerko why did you reject the two resolutions of a) Moshe did know but it's been lost or b) Moshe only needed to know how to deal with all cases of the application of the principles of halacha, not be aware of all the cases? If the principles of halacha can deal with spherical planets, as DoubleAA has insinuated, then that's (the principles are) all Moshe needed to qualify the statement "he knew all Torah"?

Comment: @RabbiKaii "Moshe did know but it's been lost" means we should admit we don't have a tradition. I agree that "Moses knew it all" is dubious, and many apologize with "knew fundamentals" or "knew basic ideas".

Comment: @AlBerko we don't have a complete tradition* isnt controversial afaik, although we have had ruach hakodesh and profound pilpullim to fill in lots of gaps, I'd be surprised if we have everything

Comment: @RabbiKaii I've pondered on the idea "had ruach hakodesh and profound pilpullim to fill in lots of gaps". It does not make sense. First, it contradicts the "Not in heaven" principle. So people resort to the "Jewish Trinity" like God and Ruach HaKodesh are both one and not one. Second, you have no mechanism for verification. IMHO, the claim that a rabbi "restored a forgotten but established tradition" is merely an excuse to promote rabbinic authority and hegemony.

Comment: @AlBerko sorry I have no idea what you mean. If you wish to discuss please open a chat.

Answer (score 2):

The question is based on a false premise.

You seem to understand that 'the Whole Torah' requires a specific knowledge and detailed understanding of every potential application. This is incorrect.

*"Knowing all the Torah"* (in relevance to Halacha) means knowing and understanding all the laws and intricacies, which can then be applied to any hypothetical scenario. If Moshe knew all the Torah, he would therefore be able to answer any halachic *shaila*, once presented with all the scientific facts.

Torah is everlasting and unchanging not because it includes a detailed list of instructions for every scenario, but because a true understanding of it's absolute principles and complex subtleties allows for application in a variable world.

Comment: So you're saying Moses did or didn't know the Earth is spherical to start with? I claim that in order to rule every Shailah about Shabbos starting time he HAD to know that fact.

Comment: And his answer directly tries to deny that claim. You only want answers that conform with your premises?